# when sortable the table, the checkbox is automatically checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have this page:

[image]

there is an option of sortable: move items from the lower table to the upper table. at this moment, I have only two items (each table has one item).

The upper table contains tasks for a worker that weren't done and the lower table contains tasks for a worker that were done.

the word: Yes/No says if the task were/weren't done.

I am trying to do the next thing:

when user move an item from the lower table to the upper table, I want the checkbox to be automatically checked (so it always move from 'Yes' to 'No').

this is my `index.html.erb` (I use `best_in_place` in order to update the database while the value is changed):

```
<html>
<body>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable"> 

  <% @tasks_worker_todo.each do |task| %>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <%= best_in_place task, :done, :classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: %w[No Yes] %> | 
            <%= task.admin_mail %> | 
            <%= task.task %>
        </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<br><br>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <% @tasks_worker_done.each do |task| %>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">
            <%= best_in_place task, :done,:classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: %w[No Yes] %> | 
            <%= task.admin_mail %> | 
            <%= task.task %>
        </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

and this is my `application.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#sortable1, #sortable2')
 .sortable(
 {'connectWith':'#sortable1',
 'dropOnEmpty':true,
 'scroll':true,
  items: "li:not(.emptyMessage)",
  receive: function(event, ui) {
         alert('moved');
         //hide empty message on receiver
         $('li.emptyMessage', this).hide();

         //show empty message on sender if applicable
         if($('li:not(.emptyMessage)', ui.sender).length == 0){
             $('li.emptyMessage', ui.sender).show();
             alert('alon');
         } else {
             $('li.emptyMessage', ui.sender).hide();
         }            
     }

  });
});
```

any help appreciated!

**Update:**

this is the HTML that ruby generates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> 
<title>TODOLIST</title> 


<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/admin.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/tasksadmins.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/workers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.purr.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/best_in_place.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/admin.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/myjquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/tasksadmins.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/workers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="FZho6dNmNWjn82HB+MzhL/MtIm4s6F7JFiLVysPCREY=" name="csrf-token" /> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="right">

    <li><a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a></li>

</div>
<p id="notice"></p>
<p id="alert"></p>
<center>
<html>
<body>


 <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable"> 


    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span class='best_in_place highlight_on_success' id='best_in_place_tasksadmin_1_done' data-url='/tasksadmins/1' data-object='tasksadmin' data-collection='["No","Yes"]' data-attribute='done' data-type='checkbox'>No</span> | 
        admin216@gmail.com | 
        feed the dog
    </li>
</ul>


<br><br>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">
        <span class='best_in_place highlight_on_success' id='best_in_place_tasksadmin_2_done' data-url='/tasksadmins/2' data-object='tasksadmin' data-collection='["No","Yes"]' data-attribute='done' data-type='checkbox'>Yes</span> | 
        admin216@gmail.com | 
        feed the fish
    </li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

p.s. I know that I have two body and two html. I will order it tomorrow.

Comment: what checkbox? post live html

Comment: Yes, can you please post the HTML that ruby generates?

Comment: there is no `input[type="checkbox"]` assume you are using a plugin to emulate checkboxes. Would need to use plugin API to manage changes. Could try just triggering `clcik` on span though

Comment: this is like checkbox, do you see the word: No/Yes of the tasks of the tables? I can press the word: "Yes", and it will be changed to "No"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the `receive` handler:

The element being moved is `ui.item`

```
 ui.item.find('span').click();
```

Comment: what a king! you helped me twice today. thank you! wish you to succeed in everything! thank you!